# Alternative Smartlock for Passwords implementation?

Tags: android, passwords, google-smartlockpasswords

I had to sign in to Netflex yesterday and got an unexpected UI. Can you tell me which library they are using? This is not the normal Smartlock for Passwords UI which I'm using in my own App.

Even on the documentation is an old screenshot of Netflix with their old UI.

[image: Netflix sign in]

Comment: Might be this one: https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/save-passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netflix uses One tap sign in provided by google
, More info you can find over this link
https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap

Comment: Yeah seems to be what I'm looking for. Thank you